# Snap vertices to a grid when moving

Tags: modeling, snapping

Similar to how you can snap UVs to the 2D pixel grid in the UV editor, can I make vertices snap to a virtual 3D grid-space where I could specify the distance between each point of the grid-space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the 3D view header, at the bottom of the 3D window change the snapping type pulldown menu to *Increment*, after that a button will appear by it's side allowing you to change the increment type to *Absolute Grid* alignment.

[image]

I am not sure but I think you can control the size of the grid in the 3D View Properties Shelf > (<kbd>N</kbd> menu) under the Display Panel > Grid Floor > Scale